# Html Table Column filter using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have copied some code from a site and made necessary changes. Here I am having a html table with two columns and multiple rows. In future I may have more columns. I need to write a single function to filter the content.  In the below code I am trying to get tds as arrays and trying to search. But the search happens only in second td. ie country names. What is the best way to write a common function to filter table contents in javascript which can be used for other tables as well.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, tdarrs, td, i, j, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tdarrs = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // alert(tdarrs[1].textContent );
    //alert( tdarrs[1].innerText);
    if (tdarrs) {
      for (j = 0; j < tdarrs.length; j++) {
        td = tdarrs[j];
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i hope this will solve your issue https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table

Comment: @JustinWilliam Page not Found

Comment: @callmenikk https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Comment: @JustinWilliam I copied the code from that site only. But what I want is I should be able to search / filter  based on the text in other columns as well.

Comment: @JAVA_CAT
What do you mean ?

Comment: The code which I copied in the question is from w3schools only.  I can filter the text in the name column but not country. I wanted to do it for all the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const trs = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    if (trs[i].textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
      trs[i].classList.remove('hidden')
    } else {
      trs[i].classList.add('hidden')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Let me try this option in my code and will surely come back. Thanks @ksav.

Comment: Here the column header gets disappeared.

Comment: I made an update. Try now